# RDCOMClient suggested in package

Tags: r, package, rdcomclient

I had my R-package using RDCOMClient via DESCRIPTION file:

Suggests: RDCOMClient

and the following (perfectly working) code:

```
GetNewWrd <- function() {

  stopifnot(require(RDCOMClient))

  # Starts the Word application with wrd as handle
  wrd <- RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Word.Application", existing=FALSE)
  newdoc <- wrd[["Documents"]]$Add("",FALSE, 0)
  wrd[["Visible"]] <- TRUE 

  invisible(wrd)
}
```

Nowadays this seems to be considered as bad practice and "Writing R Extensions, 1.1.3.1 Suggested packages" tells us to formulate:

```
if (requireNamespace("rgl", quietly = TRUE)) {
   rgl::plot3d(...)
} else {
   ## do something else not involving rgl.
}
```

or: .. *If the intention is to give an error if the suggested package is not available, simply use e.g. rgl::plot3d.*

Recoding this (to my understanding) would mean, just to delete the require-statement:

```
GetNewWrd <- function() {

  # Starts the Word application with wrd as handle
  wrd <- RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Word.Application", existing=FALSE)
  newdoc <- wrd[["Documents"]]$Add("",FALSE, 0)
  wrd[["Visible"]] <- TRUE 

  invisible(wrd)
}
```

Doing this leads to the following runtime error:

```
Error in RDCOMClient::COMCreate("Word.Application", existing = FALSE) :
  could not find function "createCOMReference"
```

createCOMReference is a function in RDCOMClient, which apparently can't be found without the explicit require statement.

How for God's sake am I supposed to integrate RDCOMClient in my package complying to CRAN's policies???

Comment: `createCOMReference` might not be exported from RDCOMClient. Have you looked at other accepted packages such as `DescTools`? Furthermore, now that I read section 1.1.3.1 again I don't think it is saying you cannot use `require`, but rather that in those cases where it is optional, that the `requireNamespace` route might create fewer problems. It is concerned that about a chance that functions could be over-written. That seems unlikely for RDCOMClient functions.

Comment: I am the author of DescTools and I wanted to upload an update. But Prof. Ripley refused  with the comment:
You did not comply with the policies re

Suggests or Enhances not in mainstream repositories:
   RDCOMClient

* checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE 'library' or 'require' call to ‘RDCOMClient’ in package code.
   Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.
   See section 'Suggested packages' in the 'Writing R Extensions'  manual.

Comment: Color me puzzled. I would have thought that OmegaHat would be considered a mainstream repo. Would there be any value in contacting Duncan Temple Lang?

Comment: :-) It's even stranger as the most current version can be found on his own Website:  http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.0/. Maybe a good idea to contact Duncan Temple Lang directly....

Answer (score 1):

Very old question, but I stumbled upon the same issue. I use the following workaround which does not issue a warning in `R CMD check` but seems to me like an awful hack:

```r
if (requireNamespace("RDCOMClient", quietly = TRUE)) {
   if (!"RDCOMClient" %in% .packages()) {
      attachNamespace("RDCOMClient")
   }
# ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a potential solution to this problem go and check out https://github.com/AndriSignorell/DescToolsAddIns/issues/1#issuecomment-1172495715 and (original solution at) https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient/issues/32#issuecomment-882969642 as long as the PR on the original repo is outstanding you can try `devtools::install_github("BSchamberger/RDCOMClient")` a fork of the RDCOMClient github repo including a "fix" for some error handling and modifications for R-4 versions as of lately.

PLUS what I also did was do "the ugly" (in the regularly discouraged method sense of the word) thing and put `RDCOMClient` in the `Depends:` (instead of the `Imports:`) section of my `DESCRIPTION` file, which at least in my case (had the same error in a dependent package) solved that `could not find createCOMReference` issue.